# How to see query exceptions in LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>.onLoadFinished()

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Say something goes wrong in a Content Provider:

```
public class MyProvider extends ContentProvider {
   // ...

   @Override
   public Cursor query(...) {
    throw new Exception("message");
   }
}
```

and we are using `getLoaderManager().initLoader(...)` and `CursorLoader` to use this Content Provider. I understand that Cursor will be null when an exception occurs but how to receive more information about the exception?

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity implements
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
   // ...

   @Override
   public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {

      if (null != cursor) { 
          // go on your merry way 
      } else {

       // HERE: find about the Exception and toast a message probably

      }
   }
```